# Writing data from C# to a MDF database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, mdf

I have a C# piece of code which listens for mouse-up events and then the data is to be written to a database. I have a `.MDF` database file I locally created in Visual Studio within the application. I am using the below code for this.

The thing is when I open the `.MDF` database file in SQL Server Management Studio after installing the application, I can't see any rows of data. I can see the columns I created but no data. The "Server" in server explorer in Visual Studio shows up to be my laptop number it seems:

```
private void MouseUpEvent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    MousePressed = e.KeyCode.ToString();
    int Counting = MousePressed.Split('/').Length - 1;
    long TimePressed = _MousePressed_Length;
    String DateToday = SQLDate;
    String TimeToday = SQLTime;
    float TimeNow = SQLTimeExactmilliseconds;
    var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var guid2 = guid + TimeNow;

    string sqlCon = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;" +
               @"AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;
                Integrated Security=True;
                Connect Timeout=30;
                User Instance=True";

    using (var db = new SqlConnection(sqlCon))
    {
        db.Open();

        var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Database1 (Table) VALUES (@Date);", db);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateToday);
        var command2 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Database1 (Table) VALUES (@Time);", db);
        command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", TimeToday);
        var command3 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Database1 (Table) VALUES (@Mousepress);", db);
        command3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mousepress", TimePressed);
        var command5 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Database1 (Table) VALUES (@TimeExact);", db);
        command5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeExact", TimeNow);
        var command6 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Database1 (Table) VALUES (@Id);", db);
        command6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", guid2);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command3.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command5.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command6.ExecuteNonQuery();

        db.Close();
    }
}
```

When I try to open the `.MDF` database file in Server Explorer, I get this message from Visual Studio :

> Database 'C:\Program Files (x86)\muhammadADIbrahim@outlook.com\Setup_Attention_Assist\Database1.mdf' already exists. Choose a different database name.
> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\muham\OneDrive\Desktop\Attention_Residue\BAAB UL WORK\NIZAM\CURRENT SOFTWARE\NizamSolutionBackup2.6\Nizam.Monitor\Database1.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

The code compiles and works properly so I am guessing this is something that is just to do with the connection to the database.

What should happen is that the `.mdf` data gets installed along with the .msi file when the user installs the application locally and the data is written to the database. For any user, I should be able to take the local `.mdf` file and open it in SQL Server Management Studio and view the results.

Thanks,
Ibrahim

Comment: You need to fix your connection string.  A MDF file can be attached to a SQL Server or opened directly from a MDF file.  Your connection string should not have both AttachFile (not attached)  and Server.  I would remove the AttachFile clause from the connection string and use the Server Name only.

Comment: Side note: [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Never use "mdf databases" on their own. SQL Server doesn't have the concept of file base DB, you always deal with a server and its installed DBs. You seem to be after a portable DB, like SQLite, rather than SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the mdf database is that you need to install SQLSever.

The problem with mySql is similar. SQLLite didn't seem to work well for me either.

I have ended up creating a .txt file for this which for now seems to be working fine.